# heroku:container M1 mac pushing docker image layer stuck in retry loop

Tags: docker, flask, heroku, containers, apple-m1

I'm trying to push my containerized Flask app to Heroku. I've read that there are issues with M1 macs here so have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.8-buster
WORKDIR /
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

I then run the following commands:

```
docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64 --no-cache  -t {name} .
heroku container:push web -a {name}
```

The build succeeds, but the push to Heroku gets stuck on a retry loop at the largest layer (8.6GB). I looked in to the layer and it runs the following:

```
<missing>      3 minutes ago    RUN /bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.t…   8.57GB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
```

Have tried a total fresh rebuild, docker prune, etc. Before the linux/amd64 option, the push to Heroku was succesful, but would crash with an Exec Error. Any ideas/thoughts much appreciated, thank you.